# How to properly pass filenames with spaces with $* from xargs to sed via sh?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, xargs, macos-big-sur

Disclaimer: this happens on macOS (Big Sur); more info about the context below.

I have to write (almost did) a script which will replace images URLs in big text (xml) files by their Base64-encoded value.

The script should run the same way with single filenames or patterns, or both, e.g.:

```
./replace-encode single.xml
./replace-encode pattern*.xml
./replace-encode single.xml pattern*.xml
./replace-encode folder/*.xml
```

Note: it should properly handle `files\ with\ spaces.xml`

So I ended up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#needed for `ls` command
IFS=$'\n'

ls -1 $* | xargs -I % sed -nr 's/.*>(https?:\/\/[^<]+)<.*/\1/p' % | xargs -tI % sh -c 'sed -i "" "s@%@`curl -s % | base64`@" $0' "$*"
```

What it does: `ls` all files, pipe the list to `xargs` then search all URLs surrounded by anchors (hence the `>` and `<` in the search expr. - also had to use `sed` because `grep` is limited on macOS), then pipe again to a `sh` script which runs the `sed` search & replace, where the remplacement is the big Base64 string.

This works perfectly fine... but only for `fileswithoutspaces.xml`

I tried to play with `$0` vs `$1`, `$*` vs `$@`, w/ or w/o `"` but to no avail.

I don't understand exactly how does the variable substitution (is it how it's called? - not a native English speaker, and above all, not a script-writer at all!!! just a Java dev. all day long...) work between `xargs`, `sh` or even `bash` with arguments like filenames.

The `xargs -t` is here to let me check out how the substitution works, and that's how I noticed that using a pattern worked but I have to let the `"` around the last `$*`, otherwise only the 1st file is searched & replaced; output is like:

```
user@host % ./replace-encode pattern*.xml
sh -c sed -i "" "s@https://www.some.com/public/123456.jpg@`curl -s https://www.some.com/public/123456.jpg | base64`@" $0 pattern_123.xml
pattern_456.xml
```

Both `pattern_123.xml` and `pattern_456.xml` are handled here; w/ `$*` instead of `"$*"` in the end of the command, only `pattern_123.xml` is handled.

So is there a simple way to "fix" this?

Thank you.

Note: macOS commands have some limitations (I know) but as this script is intended to non-technical users, I can't ask them to install (or have the IT team installed on their behalf) some alternate GNU-versions installed e.g. `pcregrep` or 'ggrep' like I've read many times...

Also: I don't intend to change from `xargs` to `for` loops or so because, 1/ don't have the time, 2/ might want to optimize the 2nd step where some URLs might be duplicate or so.

Comment: `$*` is never safe for arbitrary filenames. You _must_ use `"$@"` -- remember, filenames can even contain newlines! If someone creates a file with `touch $'foo\nbar.xml'`, anything that uses newline-separated names will never be able to handle it.

Comment: Also, `ls` output should only be used by humans, never software. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Why all the `ls` and `$*` mess instead of just `sed -nr 's/.*>(https?:\/\/[^<]+)<.*/\1/p' "$@"`?

Comment: Also, `xargs -I% sh -c '...%...'` opens you up to serious security problems. Think about what happens if you're processing a file named `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.xml` (yes, it's a valid name). In general, don't generate code as strings unless you have no other choice.

Comment: I know (or discovered while reading the manuals & questions here on SO) all of this, but 1/ end users are NOT supposed to create files by themselves in the CLI (they're just former basic Windows users), 2/ script is not meant to be widely distributed (used only in 1 team of these users)

Comment: Writing software that handles only things that are _supposed_ to happen means a field day for a pentester (or worse, a black-hat) trying to find and exploit such assumptions.

Comment: (Re: edit) You only have the time to use tools that _don't work_? Okay, then.

Comment: (and the answer I gave you already deduplicates URLs; that's what the `sort -u` does).

Comment: Again, that's just a one-off tool meant to be used by end-users not keen with CLI and in the process there won't be any file named like `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.xml` (and even if it does, that wouldn't be my problem, it's theirs...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up with this single-line script:

```
sed -nr 's/.*>(https?:\/\/[^<]+)<.*/\1/p' "$@" | xargs -I% sh -c 'sed -i "" "s@%@`curl -s % | base64`@" "$@"' _ "$@"
```

which does properly support filenames with or without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for your software to use `ls` or `xargs`, and certainly not `$*`.

```
./replace-encode single.xml
./replace-encode pattern*.xml
./replace-encode single.xml pattern*.xml
./replace-encode folder/*.xml
```

...will all work fine with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  replacement=$(curl -s "$line" | base64)
  in="$line" out="$replacement" perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' "$@"
done < <(sed -nr 's/.*>(https?:\/\/[^<]+)<.*/\1/p' "$@" | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: `base64 | tr -d '\n'` would be more portable but not required in macOS